# Correct interpretation of "A ray of light makes an angle of $10^\circ$ with the horizontal above it"

Tags: geometry, angle

I encountered this problem in Physics and the direction chosen by me was different from that used in the answer hence I got the wrong answer. The problem here is in the mathematical interpretation of a statement hence I'm posting it on Maths SE. The question goes like this:

> A ray of light makes an angle of $10^\circ$ with the horizontal above
> it and strikes a plane mirror which is inclined at some angle to the
> horizontal. We need to find the angle for which the light becomes
> vertical after reflection.

[image]

However I think this diagram is wrong; and when it states that it makes the angle "with the horizontal above it", it should indicate that the light ray would make an angle of $10^\circ$ clockwise with the horizontal. If I use that, I get the answer to be $40^\circ$.

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you, but I don't think there is a "correct" interpretation of this, as much as just ambiguous language. I can see why it might be interpreted both ways.

Comment: Oh so what would be a way to make it more rigorous eitherways? @EeveeTrainer

Comment: @DinoManPhyLab: One fix might be to write that the ray "makes an angle of $10^\circ$ above (or below) the horizontal". ... Generally, it probably is *reasonable* to expect that when "a ray makes an (unqualified) angle with the horizontal" that the ray is more-likely-than-not *above* the horizontal, as we tend to use "the horizontal" as a *base* for a scenario. The problem's use of "above it" is definitely confusing, though, as the antecedent of "it" isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture bellow is the third angle in the triangle denoted $\beta.$ Then $$10^{\circ}+180^{\circ}-\theta + \beta=180^{\circ},$$
therefore $$\beta=\theta-10^{\circ}.$$

[image]